# inconveniente CASE WHEN SQL

Tags: sql, usecase

Estoy intentando poner la condicion en el case when que si un usuario su diferencia de dias es mayor a 7 y su numero de transacciones es mayor a 10 me ponga que es un usuario retenido y si no se cumplen estas dos condiciones es un usuario nuevo, pero me trae por ejemplo un usuario que la diferencia de días es de 27 y el numero de transacciones es de 4, es decir solo cumplo 1 pero me lo pone como un usuario retenido, como lo podría corregir

```
WITH usuarios bloqueados as (
                        select 
                        a.store_id,
                        nombre, 
                        estado_caso,
                        motivo,
                        cast(fecha as date) as date_blocked,
                        cast(min(b.created_at) as date) as first_trx,
                        count(b.transaction_id) as num_Trx
                        from `Uaruarios_Bloqueados` a 
                        left join `transaction` b
                        on a.store_id = b.store_id 
                        where b.status = "APPROVED"
                        group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

)

```
select c.store_id,
       c.nombre, 
       c.estado_caso,
       c.motivo,
       c.date_blocked,
       c.first_trx,
       DATE_DIFF(c.date_blocked, c.first_trx,day) as diff_days,
       (select count(d.transaction_id)
        from transaction as d
        where d.store_id = c.store_id and date(d.created_at) between c.first_trx and  c.date_blocked and d.status =   'APPROVED' ) num_trx,
        ***case WHEN DATE_DIFF(c.date_blocked, c.first_trx,day) > 7 and num_trx >= 10 THEN "usuario retenido"
        else "usuario nuevo"
        END as status
        from usuarios bloqueados as c
        order by date_blocked asc***
```

Comment: POn ola consulta completa

Comment: ¿Cuál motor usas y qué tipo de dato es `num_trx`?

Comment: ya esta la query completa, es en GCP, num_Trx es una cuenta de un id que es un tipo de dato integer

Comment: ¿Estás consciente de que la columna `num_trx` que estás usando en el `CASE` no es la misma que aparece en el resultado de la consulta?